# Gimp does not remember my last brush

Tags: gimp

I often paint on screenshots to highlight parts. I like a 4 pixel pink brush fot this.

Unfortunately Gimp does not remember my last setting. After starting Gimp again the brush is 20 pixel and black.

Why does Gimp not remember my last setting?

Comment: Please check file permissions of GIMP configuration folders. Add output of  `ls -ald ~/.gimp-2.*` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

From GIMP, click on the Edit Menu and select Preferences.  Then select Tool Options.  Click on "Save Tool Options Now" to save it as default when you reopen GIMP.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Gimp has really two modes of operations:

1) Current settings are saved when you exit, so you start a session with the settings you used in the previous one. This is preferred if you work on big projects in several sessions.

2) Settings are saved once for all, so you always start with the same settings. This is usually preferred if you work on varied small projects.

You can choose between the two using `Edit>Preferences>Tool options>Save tool options on exit` **and since Gimp 2.10**, `Edit>Preferences>Input devices>Save input device settings on exit`.

If you choose option #2, you can set the start options by setting everything as you like (colors, brush, pattern, font, gradient, and options in about every tool), then activating your default tool, and clicking `Edit>Preferences>Tool options>Save tool options now` and `Edit>Preferences>Input devices>Save input device settings now`.